# How to import variable from another file in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a variable "OTPN" in an otp_fun file and I want to import that variable to the Main file, I tried by importing "From otp_fun import otpn", But it is throwing an error

```
otp_fun file code   

def otp():
    new = int(random.random()*1000000)
    global otpn
    otpn = round(new,6)



main file code

from Contacts.otp_fun import otp,otpn
```

it has to import otpn variable but it is throwing an error saying 
" ImportError: cannot import name 'otpn' from 'Contacts.otp_fun"

Answer (score 1):

You cannot import `otpn` because it has not been defined, you see it is defined in `otp`, but this variable will only be made available after calling it.

You may think a solution would be to define `otpn` in global scope with a default value like this:

```
otp_fun file code 

otpn = None

def otp():
    new = int(random.random()*1000000)
    global otpn
    otpn = round(new,6)
```

But if you import it using `from Contacts.otp_fun import otpn` and then call `otp` you will see the value does not change :(

```
main file code

from otp_fun import otpn, otp

print(otpn)
# prints None

otp()

print(otpn)
# prints None
```

To keep the value linked you want to import the whole module with `import Contacts.otp_fun`.

```
main file code

import otp_fun

print(otp_fun.otpn)
# prints None

otp_fun.otp()
# changes otpn value

print(otp_fun.otpn)
# prints some random number
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Class`:

otp_fun file code :

```
import random


class Otp():
    def otp(self):
        new = int(random.random() * 1000000)
        global otpn
        otpn = round(new, 6)
        return otpn
```

main file code:

```
from Contacts.otp_fun import Otp

myVariable = Otp()

print(myVariable.otp())
```