# How can I move the "cost" argument from inside of 'MENU' to a separate python file?

Tags: python

```
    drink = input("Would you like to buy a espresso, latte or cappuccino?:\n").lower()
    if drink == "espresso":
        print(MENU["cost"])
```

I am getting this error when I try to input something. Can anyone help?

File "C:\Users\joeca\Udemy\Games\Day10\Coffee Machine.py", line 25, in purchase
print(MENU["cost"])
KeyError: 'cost'

I was hoping that I could move this 'cost' argument to a separate file in order for it to be easily viewed and altered.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import variable from another file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57265066/how-to-import-variable-from-another-file-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this `MENU["cost"]` mean that `MENU` is a dictionary and you try to get value of `'cost'` key from that dictionary 
the error shows you that in dictionary `MENU` there is no such key/value pair with the `'cost'` key

Comment: It's beacuse it's inside the argument. e.g.MENU = {
    "espresso": {
        "ingredients": {
            "water": 50,
            "coffee": 18,
        },
        "cost": 1.5,
    },                                                                                  So they are in separate lines to one another and are indented and im not sure how to get them out of thios

Comment: So you want `MENU[drink]['cost']`?

Comment: Oh, I didn't realise I could do that. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

In general, you would do it this way:

```
from othermodule import othervariable

drink = input("...").lower()
if drink == "espresso":
    print(MENU[othervariable])
```